# ¿Cómo reemplazar letra en JavaScript con replace?

Tags: javascript, replace

Hola tengo input que genera slug a travez del título pero resulta que los caracteres 'á','é','í','ó','ú' son reemplazados por: '' Como puedo hacer que un carácter á se reemplace por a;
Ejemplo: Si el título es: **Maléfica: Dueña del Mal**. Generé un slug de: **malefica-duena-del-mal**

Este es el trozo de código que ejecuta la función:

```
$("#title").val(title);
                            //slug
                            title = title.toLowerCase(); // Hace la minúscula
                            title = title.replace(/[^\w ]+/g, ''); // Reemplaza las tildes en vacío
                            title = title.replace(/ +/g, '-'); // Hace un '-' en los espacios
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hay que utilizar varios **regex** para hacer lo que estas pidiendo, pero aquí esta.

```js
// Lo agregamos al prototype de string para su reutilización como libreria
String.prototype.clean = function(){
  var _thisstr = this; // Asignamos el string actual
  _thisstr = _thisstr.normalize("NFD") // Normalizamos para obtener los códigos
                .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f|.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "") // Quitamos los acentos y símbolos de puntuación
                .replace(/ +/g, '-') // Reemplazamos los espacios por guiones
                .toLowerCase(); // Todo minúscula
  return _thisstr;
};

var str = "Maléfica: La dueña del mal";
console.log(str.clean());
```

Answer (score 2):

yo te recomendaría usar la librería [Slugfy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify)

```js
const slug = slugify('Maléfica: Dueña del Mal.', { lower: true, remove: /[*+~.()'"!:@]/g} );
console.log(slug);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slugify@1.4.4/slugify.min.js"></script>
```